# dotnetnuke 5.5 critical error on pressing settings on every module of the site

Tags: dotnetnuke

my site was hosted on one server . everything was working fine. After moving to another server . click on the settings of every module on the site give critical error object reference not set to instance of an object. what could be wrong? i am using dotnetnuke 5.5

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in Admin >> Event Viewer ?

Comment: If not, change the debugmode in web.config to true and then recreate the problem. We need more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the files you skip the Install/Setup step where the install wizard checks your folder permissions.  Start there, check that first: [Setting Security Permissions](http://www.installationwiki.org/DotNetNuke#Setting_Security_Permissions)